# Checking for divisors till max{2 ≤ i ≤ n} (min (i,n/i))?

Tags: math

My prof gave an alternative explanation for checking till sqrt(n) by replying this:

"We need to check for divisors only till max<sub>2 ≤ i ≤ n</sub>(min(i, n/i)). 
The maximum is attained when i = n/i, ie. i = sqrt n."

What does he even mean? Can someone put it in English?

Comment: Maybe you meant to ask this on [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This is massively lacking context. I am assuming that you are talking in the context of checking a number for primality?

Comment: Yes, a check for primality. I just dont understand why we check till sqrt(n) rather than min(i,n/i)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting the TeX for you, that's "max<sub>2 <= i <= n</sub>(min(i, n/i))". In English, the largest value of the smaller of `i` and `n/i` over all values of `i` from 2 up to `n`.

For example, if `n` is 12:

```
i    n/i    min(i,n/i)
2    6      2
3    4      3    <--- Largest value is 3: sqrt(12) rounded down
4    3      3
5    2      2
6    2      2
7    1      1
8    1      1
9    1      1
10   1      1
11   1      1 
12   1      1
```

It's quite easy to see that `i < n/i` if and only if `i < sqrt(n)`, and from that we can see that the largest value of that expression will be `sqrt(n)`.

Presumably, this is for finding the factors of `n`. If `i` is a factor, then `n/i` also is, since `n/i * i = n`, so there's no need to test both `i` and `n/i`. Therefore, we can choose only to check the smaller of the two, `min(i, n/i)`, and only need consider values of `i` up to the largest such value - which is the value of the expression your teacher gave you.

Comment: Dear Mike, I know you have simplified the equation into english for me. But still, I do not understand what "the largest value of the smaller of i and n/i over all values of i from 2 up to n" means. Do you mind simplifying it a little further?I am a freshie... sorry if i sound real green.

Comment: @user2000304: For each value of `i` from 2 up to `n`, take the smaller value of `i` and `n/i`. Look at all of those values, and take the largest of them.

Comment: Dear Mike. I very much appreciate your table! Is it correct to say that we Do Not need to consider cases where n/i > i, because these cases are just a repeat of the cases where i > n/i?

Comment: @user2000304: Yes. Once `i` is larger than the square-root, `n/i` must be less than the square-root, and therefore is a repeat of a smaller value of `i`.

Comment: Perfect. I think they key sentence to this proof was "For each value of i from 2 up to n, take the smaller value of i and n/i". Thanks a bunch Mike, I wish You were my teacher. Lol. Problem solved and proved. Thank you.